# Sublime Text Search and Insert

Tags: text, editor, sublimetext

I want to change the below in sublime or anything text editor from

1   ABCWF
  2   CDFDDD
  4   IHGNMM

to
  1   'ABCWF'
  2   'CDFDDD'
  4   'IHGNMM'

I have over 1000 records. Is there a way that I don't do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A purely sublime answer would be:

1. In Sublime highlight one instance of the text you want changed: `1 ABCWF 2 CDFDDD 4 IHGNMM`

[image: highlight a single instance]

2. Press Alt+F3 on Windows and Linux, or Ctrl+Command+G on OS X, this will select all of your 1000s of instances of `1 ABCWF 2 CDFDDD 4 IHGNMM` for editing simultaneously

[image: Selects all instances]

3. Use the arrow keys on your keyboard to move your cursor to the correct position in the string to make edits.

[image: simultaneously change all instances]

4. Make the edits. All 1000 instances will be revised at the same time.

[image: Done]

Source for my answer: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html

Comment: Alternatively, you can highlight the text you want to edit, press `Ctrl+D` to select the next occurence

Comment: @DominatorX You're right `Ctrl+D` is effective for editing a few instances simultaneously; however, in this question the OP would have to press `Ctrl+D` 1000 times since the OP has over 1000 instances of the record that need to be edited.

Comment: Yes indeed.  Is it possible to hold `Ctrl+D` and have it select all the instances?